# How to prove that idempotency is redundant here in lattices?

Tags: lattice-orders

In ['A Course in Universal Algebra'](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~snburris/htdocs/UALG/univ-algebra2012.pdf) (Stanley Burris and H. P. Sankappanavar) definition 1.1 a lattice is presented to me as non-empty set $L$ together with binary operations $\wedge$ and $\vee$ that meet the following conditions:

1) $x\vee y=y\vee x$ and $x\wedge y=y\wedge x$

2) $x\vee\left(y\vee z\right)=\left(x\vee y\right)\vee z$ and $x\wedge\left(y\wedge z\right)=\left(x\wedge y\right)\wedge z$

3) $x\vee x=x$ and $x\wedge x=x$

4) $x\vee\left(x\wedge y\right)=x$ and $x\wedge\left(x\vee y\right)=x$

In exercise 1.2 it is asked to verify that condition 3) is a
consequence of the conditions 1), 2) and 4).

I am stuck and humbly ask for help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x\vee x=s$. It follows from 4) $x\wedge s=x$. Hence $x\vee x=x\vee (x\wedge s)=x$ (again from 4)).

Comment: Thank you. I wonder why it is mentioned as condition while it is redundant. Maybe that will become clear later in the book.

Comment: I don't know. Happy New Year!

Comment: Happy new year to you as well, my Russian friend.